# SOQL Type conversion (SalesForce.com)

Tags: type-conversion, salesforce, soql

The problem is that I need to compare two fields of different types in a SOQL query.

TextField is a Picklist (so really text) and IntField is a Number(2, 0).  Changing the types of these fields is not possible.

I would like to write SOQL like;

```
SELECT Id FROM SomeObject__c
WHERE Cast(TextField as Integer) > IntField
```

Obviously `Cast(TextField as Integer)` does NOT work.

Any advise on type conversion within SOQL.  The normal APEX functions (e.g. integer.valueof) don't seem to be of any help here.

Thanks

Comment: @OMG Ponies - this is not a SQL Query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOQL itself does not support casting but you can always lend a helping hand ;)

Create a Numeric formula field in `SomeObject__c`:

```
IF(ISNUMBER(TextField__c), VALUE(TextField__c), NULL)
```

or something similar depending on your definition of cast to int. Now you can use this field in a SOQL query.

Comment: Wanted to add two tidbits of information to this answers for the final solutions I needed;
1) You cannot compare two values on the object in SOQL - so I added that to the formula
2) You cannot call ISNUMBER (and may other functions) on PickLists - so I added a convert for that too

Final formula looks like;
IF(ISNUMBER(TEXT(TextField__c)), VALUE(TEXT(TextField__c)), NULL) - IntField

Then you just eval against this in the SOQL query.  Oh the joys of SFDC

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the part where you said picklist or I would have given you a complete formula. I saw TextField in your code sample and went with that.

Comment: no worries - you sent me down the right path.  Granted not what I wanted to hear, but I often find with SFDC that I can't do things in a way that feels natural (i.e. just have all this in the query) and have to employ workarounds.